# Objective-C iOS catch a js/html event

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Im just starting with objective-c/ios and i am trying to catch an event from html embebed in a uiwebview.

In android you can do it with a js interface.

I already manage to call a js function from ios, now i need to do the opposite.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have `Objective`-C code mixed with an `HTML` file that runs locally on a UIWebView. That said, there are some workarounds that may fit your needs.

One that I've used, is to have the HTML link to a custom URL, and detect that on the appropriate method in the UIWebView delegate class, as follows:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

In that method, you would check for the URL schema you created by means of checking the request parameter, and then decide what selector to code on your Objective-C code.

[see this blog for simple function call.](http://davinccoder.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/call-ios-method-for-html-button-click/)

[another blog for your reqirement](http://iosameer.blogspot.in/2012/09/bridge-between-javascripthtml-and.html)

Comment: Yes! I find a similar solution in another post, and it work. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the phone gap framework in objective C. I have used the same in my phonegap project to call the device token.

Here is the sample which is used in javascript.

```
                                                                                                                                   cordova.exec(null, null, "deviceCls", "getDeviceToken", [args]
```

You have to point your class(deviceCls) to the phonegap plugin plist.

Check the phone gap links [here](http://phonegap.com)